# How to disable checkbox of root Item in the SWT java

Tags: java, checkbox, tree, swt

[image]

In the above link of image, I want to disable checkbox of Root Item and child, I want to set selection for GrtandChild Item.
Please tell me know the way to do it on SWT .
Thanks

Comment: I can not access the link you have posted due to a 404 error.

Comment: I've just uploaded my image into other host.

Answer (score 2):

There are no **real** methods of disabling a TreeItem.

Your options are:

*greyed* (partially selected) using: `treeItem.setGrayed(true);`

*checked* using: `treeItem.setChecked(true);`

*unchecked* using: `treeItem.setChecked(false);`

Some people workaround this limitation by using an event listener on a `SWT.Selection` and then uncheck any item that should not be checked. An example can be found here: [Disable TreeItem & Grayout Discussion](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t81749.html)